# why i cannot print information in a object on to the console

Tags: flutter, dart

why i cannot print the following statements in dart:

```
print(questionBank[1].questionAnswer);
print(questionBank.length);
```

=====================================================

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({String ques, bool ans}) {
    questionText = ques;
    questionAnswer = ans;
  }
}
      
        void main{
            List<Question> questionBank = [
                Question(
                    ques: 'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.', ans: false),
                Question(
                    ques: 'Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.',
                    ans: true),
                Question(ques: 'A slug\'s blood is green.', ans: true),
              ];
            
              print(questionBank[1].questionAnswer);
              print(questionBank.length);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to override the method `toString` like this:

```
@override
String toString() => 'Question{questionText: $questionText, questionAnswer: $questionAnswer}';
```

and after that you can do :

```
print(yourObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is your model insert toString method, by right click in your model>genrate>toString() '(Android studio)'**

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({String ques, bool ans}) {
    questionText = ques;
    questionAnswer = ans;
  }


  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Question{questionText: $questionText, questionAnswer: $questionAnswer}';
  }
```

}

**then use like:**

```
debugPrint(questionBank[1].questionAnswer.toString());
```